# Use MacBook as VPN server or outbound proxy

Tags: linux, macos, router, vpn, proxy

I'm not sure whether the question's title describes what I'm trying to achieve...

Anyway, it is coronavirus outbreak, and I'm grounded at home. My employer has very strict security/hardware polices that allow only company-approved laptops (MacBooks) to connect to the most of company resources. On top of that we can connect only through VPN. At home I have pretty powerful linux machine that is collecting dust, while it can save hours of compile time/time to spin up docker containers, etc...

I have full admin access both to my Mac, Linux machine and home router, so I got the idea that I can use Mac as VPN or proxy server to connect to corporate network from my Linux machine:

Linux workstation ---- (VPN or Proxy config + some router network magic) ---> MacBook --- VPN ----> Corporate Network

Does it sound like a feasible solution?

**Bonus question:**

I do lots work through terminal, so it'd be nice if this setup will make it work seamless as well (i.e. can I just copy my SSH private/public keys from Mac to Linux machine or proxy SSH/CMD things as well)?

In case it matters for answer:
Router: Netgear c3700
Mac OS version: Catalina 10.15.4
Linux machine OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: good question. same scenario on here. My 2017 macbook air is so slowwwwwwwwwwwww. i'd prefer develop on my Linux workstation

Comment: this worked for me: https://superuser.com/a/201132/266547

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "borrowing" mac address from the work laptop will be the easiest solution.

To lookup mac address on MacBook the following command can be used:

```
$ ifconfig
...
en0: flags=...
        ...
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Or via GUI: `System Preferences -> Network -> WiFi -> Advanced (button) -> Hardware (tab) -> Mac Address`

To set the address on the Linux machine the following command should make the trick:

```
macchanger -m xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx eth0
```

Installation instructions, just in case you don't have `macchanger` installed:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y macchanger
```

There are probably some ethical concerns with workarounding rules set by company's security team... I feel like asking them to allow-list your workstation would be a better solution `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

Comment: well... it not worked for me